# Opening PDF drawings with comments

Tags: pdf

On some of my PDF drawings the Engineers review stamp block is covering a portion of the drawing.  I am using Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 -7.0 with ice cream to view this drawing.  I did not have any issues viewing the same drawing with the same "Engineers approval" stamp on my Windows 7 desktop. Can someone tell me if there is a solution or if this is an issue with Adobe Reader 10.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ezPDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader.lite) to view that file.

Comment: +1, it does just about everything for PDFs

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be one of two things: either it could be a problem with the PDF reader on the Samsung Galaxy Tab ***or*** that the different screen resolution is just making both images appear on top of one another (more likely). Since the tab has a smaller screen it could be "warping" the image to appear differently when in actuality there's nothing wrong with the PDF. You'll need to shrink that PDF.

There are many PDF viewers on the market that will allow you to view PDFs accurately if the PDF reader is the problem. A simple market search for "PDF" should turn up a number of readers. You can try this approach but it's also likely that the reader on the tab is merely warping the image and that there's nothing inherently wrong with the reader itself.

More likely, you can try shrinking your PDFs down to an appropriate size if they're too large. From what you're describing this may very well be the problem, your exact problem may be occurring because the images within the PDF are extremely large.

They can be trimmed down. This will also reduce the overall file size of the PDF (desirable). For more information see: http://www.ehow.com/how_4937702_reduce-pdf-file-size-easily.html